# What is a way to play an mp3 and modify it's pitch in a Windows 10 Universal App ?

Tags: audio, mp3, windows-10, win-universal-app, sharpdx

I can play mp3s with the AudioGraph class but I cannot find a way to change the pitch of the mp3..

So I went back to SharpDX nuget  and that is not compatible with Win 10 Apps. So How can I do this ? I would think it would not be so hard.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called PlaybackSpeedFactor in the AudioFileInputNode, I change it and works really well. As an example I change it when I finish playing to get a random speed:

```
private void FileInput_FileCompleted(AudioFileInputNode sender, object args)
    {
        if (CanChangeSpeed)
        {
            sender.PlaybackSpeedFactor = (double)generator.Next(6,12) / 10.0;
        }
    }
```